# Change search path in QTextEdit

Tags: python, html, pyqt, qtextedit, qtextdocument

I've read about QTextBrowser, where you can add SearchPaths. Is there a way to implement the same thing in QTextEdit?

Background:

I want to load a HTML file in QTextEdit. Using .setHtml it loads the text, but not the images. Any browser loads everything correctly. 
Example html:

```
<img src="b69b37f9a55946e38923b760ab86ee71.png" />
```

I figured out, that Python/Qt can't find the image, because it needs the full path. However, I dont want to save the full path in my html file. (Because later on I might change the location).

If I change the working directory with os.chdir(), it loads the image, but if I change it back, the image isnt shown once again. Also this solutions seems very tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QTextBrowser's `searchPaths()` method has nothing to do with what you want since it has another goal.

---

On the other hand, the relative routes are resolved using the url associated with `QTextDocument::DocumentUrl` as indicated by [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#MetaInformation-enum):

> **QTextDocument::DocumentTitle**  0   The title of the document.
>   **QTextDocument::DocumentUrl**   1   The url of the document. The
>   loadResource() function uses this url as the base when loading
>   relative resources.

In addition, this behavior is easily observed in [the implementation](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/gui/text/qtextdocument.cpp?h=5.14#n2205).

So the solution is to set the path of the directory where the image is:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()

    directory = "/path/of/image_directory"
    w.document().setMetaInformation(
        QtGui.QTextDocument.DocumentUrl,
        QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(directory).toString() + "/",
    )

    HTML = """<img src="b69b37f9a55946e38923b760ab86ee71.png"/>"""
    w.setHtml(HTML)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```